# typescript/eslint rule for function syntax in objects implementing interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

JavaScript (and TypeScript) offers two ways to define functions when letting an object implement an interface. Consider this code sample:

```
export interface ITest {
    start(): ITest;
    stop(): ITest;
}

const instance: ITest = {
    start: () => instance,
    stop() { return this; },
}
```

I'd like to enforce a consistent code style and need to disable the second style (without `:`). Is there a `typescript-eslint` rule for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the `typescript-eslint` rules list but unfortunately I couldn't identify anything from the rule names that seemed to fit what you are looking for.

Here's the full rules list from their repository:
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules